# Deserialize Arraylist of objects

Tags: java, object, serialization, arraylist

I am dealing with a utterly painful puzzle I cannot solve... While I have been able to serialize/deserialize single objects I  find myself stuck at the moment. The reason is that I am working with an ArrayList of objects, and cannot figure it out... So far I have managed to write it to a file, FootballClub.ser. This one below is my best attempt, but I get

***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to FootballClubNL***

```
public class FootballClubFileWriter {

    private static final String filename_1 = "FootballClub.ser";
    private static final String filename_2 = "FootballClub.txt"; //Use for question 5

    public static void serializeToDisk(ArrayList<FootballClubNL> clubs) throws IOException {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename_1);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(clubs);
            fos.close();
            oos.close();
    }


    public static ArrayList<FootballClubNL> deserializeFromDisk()throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        ArrayList<FootballClubNL> desrializaedClubs = new ArrayList<FootballClubNL>();

        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("FootballClub.ser");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

        FootballClubNL club = (FootballClubNL)in.readObject();

        return desrializaedClubs;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You serialized a `List` but you are deserializing to `FootballClubNL`. Just change this line

```
FootballClubNL club = (FootballClubNL)in.readObject();
```

to

```
desrializaedClubs = (ArrayList<FootballClubNL>)in.readObject();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
desrializaedClubs = (ArrayList<FootballClubNL>)in.readObject();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your file contains a List of FootballClubNL and that's exactly what's been returned from the `in.readObject()`, so you must cast it to a `ArrayList<FootballClubNL>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to deserialize an array int  FootballClubNL.. 
try the following

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FootballClubFileWriter {

    private static final String filename_1 = "FootballClub.ser";
    private static final String filename_2 = "FootballClub.txt"; //Use for question 5

    public static void serializeToDisk(ArrayList<FootballClubNL> clubs) throws IOException {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename_1);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(clubs);
            fos.close();
            oos.close();
    }


    public static ArrayList<FootballClubNL> deserializeFromDisk()throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        ArrayList<FootballClubNL> desrializaedClubs = new ArrayList<FootballClubNL>();

        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("FootballClub.ser");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

        **ArrayList<FootballClubNL> club = (ArrayList<FootballClubNL>)in.readObject();**

        return club;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to get the Object. It's only fictiv code... You can do something like this:

```
Object readObject = in.readObject();;
if(readObject instanceof FootballClubNL){
   FootballClubNL club = (FootballClubNL) readObject;
}
```

Here you can check out if the readed object is an instance of an footballclub, than it will cast it!

Answer (score -2):

Cast it as a ArrayList

```
    List<FootballClubNL> clubs = (ArrayList<FootballClubNL> )in.readObject();
```

Comment: This won't even compile.